# How to switch the buttons in a navigation drawer into spinners

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

So I am looking at the navigation drawer template(android studio implementation) and am looking to customize it. I see that there is a menu xml file for the drawer(along with the 4 other XML files for this activity) however this seems to be different than the layout xml and the options available to me are much more limited(Menu item, Search item,Switch item). How do I add spinner widgets(or any widgets for that matter) to there instead?
Edit: yeah its kind of hard to describe. trying to modify this:[Image shows the layout I want to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3awo9.png) 
The only reference to the things such as: import,gallery and so on are in this menu xml[Picture shows the XML editor for the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGsjG.png)
So I guess the question is how do I edit the stuff below the green on image 1 with a normal xml layout file rather than a menu file? 
it used a menu file by default for some reason.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.Edit the question and  Add some code or a picture of what you want to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood reading your question is you want to add spinner to the navigation drawer.If yes, then this can help.
Yes, there is no direct way available to add spinner to a NavigationDrawer but you can link another XML file containing spinner with existing menu.xml. Use this.

- First, add a link to another layout file

  ```
    <item
      android:id="@+id/spinner1"
      app:actionLayout="@layout/spinner1"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/spinner_image"
      android:title="Use it or leave it"
      />
  ```
- Second, create a layout named spinner1 (same as in item you've added
  in menu.xml)

  ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Spinner 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:gravity="center_vertical" />
  ```
- Finally, link the spinner in your java file.

  ```
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.spinner1).getActionView();
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,yourarraylist);
     spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {  
        Toast.makeText(YouActivity.this,yourarraylist[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      //DO something
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Yes. this is what I want to do